# What is the best approach for UI kit?

Tags: gui-design, buttons, guidelines, human-interface-guideline, shape

I have a dilemma at work and that is that we have many types of buttons: filled and lined black, light blue, dark blue in different shapes, round and rectangular with slightly rounded edges. We also have text only buttons. And all of them with and without icon.
In three different sizes: large, medium, small.
My suggestion has been to simplify the UI kit to just one color, two sizes and one type of shape.

What do you think about this?[image]

Comment: Although the image helps to understand the problem, in order to offer a coherent answer it's necessary to completely contextualize the project. With only this info, the possible answers are: all the buttons are necessary, there are many buttons, and the chosen option of only two colors and sizes is the right one.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to edit the question to provide more context?

Comment: Of course, there's an Edit button at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1):

A great design system starts with a strong set of definitions and user requirements for each element.

Your button set is no exception. Start by understanding the use cases for buttons disregarding what buttons you already have. Usually, you will end up with a set of at least two button types: "Primary" (the button you want the user to hit or that your research shows the user will want to hit the most) and "Secondary" (buttons that need to be a part of the UI but are less important than the primary). Lots of design systems will have a third button just to enable greater depth in the hierarchy.

Regardless of how many buttons your design system has, each one should have a set of definitions and user requirements that they fulfil. If a button exists but does NOT fulfil any user requirements then it is not needed.

The Primary button in a design system should normally only appear once on any given interface - This tells the user what the objective is. There may be other buttons required to fulfil all other scenarios but the Primary states the end goal. It could be that this is "Save" or "add to basket" or even "Wipe This Hard Drive" but it's the only Primary on the page.

With that in mind, consistency throughout your product is important. If your Primary keeps changing colour from page to page, you may end up confusing your users. They may end up wondering if that IS the Primary or something else. Even if only slight, this can be enough to cost your users' trust.

If the different colours are for different products then you should probably have different design systems for each product to avoid the designer becoming confused about which colour they should use for each product.

In short, do not just blindly delete buttons unless you know that they have no user requirement to satisfy. But also, delete any buttons that do not have a user requirement to satisfy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It makes perfect sense. 
I wonder if the color change from one product to another might be confusing to users. 
From my point of view, it is. But it is true that each product needs a slightly different entity. 
I don't know if you have examples of brands that do this in a decent way.
Thank you very much again for your reply.